# Canceling 'out of view' view background tasks in a GridView

Tags: android, image, gridview, android-asynctask, android-adapter

I'm looking for someway to register when an item in a GridView (or ListView probably too) is removed or it's content is removed, or no longer visible so that a background task can be canceled immediately.

If my Grid looks like this:

```
* * *
* * *
* * *
```

Each dot representing images loaded from the device, in a background tasks.
Then scroll down very quickly before all images have been rendered, it will still wait for all the tasks to be completed.

How do I can cancel this? Can't seem to do it from the Adapter.

If the first row (up) is out of the "picture" so to speak, cancel those three tasks if there are any there and immediately load the third row (down).

Do I call this from the GridView or do I handle this from the adapter. Tried looking for an event from the ImageView that lets me know if it's out of focused or it's contents have been removed. Not found anything. Since the View's are being reused too.

Example:

```
* * * <- Not visible, cancel loading task (at the moment will finish loading these images)
- - -
* * *
* * *
* * * <- Now visible, prioritize these (these will come last, not first)
- - -
* * * <- Not visible yet
* * * <- Not visible yet
```

Comment: typically views that stop being visible is recycled. You can get hold of the now hidden view in the `getView` of your adapter (the convertView)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't load images while you are scrolling  ,So you can add scrolling listener to your GridView/ListView and when user is scrolling you should cancel loading images.

```
  gridView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView listView, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                //stop loading
            } else {
                //start loading
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        }
    });
```

More information :

http://leftshift.io/6-ways-to-make-your-lists-scroll-faster-than-the-wind

Comment: On scrolling I set a variable to the adapter to not load any images, when changed to idle I set it to load images again. But I need to call notifyData for it to do anything afterwards. Although old images already loaded (but correct images at position), gets loaded again with this method. This is not exactly optimal.

Comment: @Deukalion cache your images with `LruCache` .see this link http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html